# Recursive function in ci

Tags: php, recursion

```
Array (
 [0] => Array ( [menu_id] => 1 [menu_title] => Home [menu_link] => home [parent_menu] => 0 [menu_pos] => H [status] => Y ) 
 [1] => Array ( [menu_id] => 2 [menu_title] => About [menu_link] => about [parent_menu] => home [menu_pos] => H [status] => Y ) 
 [2] => Array ( [menu_id] => 4 [menu_title] => test1 [menu_link] => test1 [parent_menu] => about [menu_pos] => H [status] => Y ) 
 [3] => Array ( [menu_id] => 5 [menu_title] => Help [menu_link] => help [parent_menu] => about [menu_pos] => H [status] => Y ) 
 [4] => Array ( [menu_id] => 7 [menu_title] => test_new [menu_link] => test [parent_menu] => test [menu_pos] => H [status] => Y ) 
)
```

i want to get menu link, sub link by using parent menu .i print the array please help me out.

```
public function menu ($type)
{

    $pages = $this->ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".MENU." WHERE menu_pos='".$type."'")->result_array();

    $array = $pages;
            //print_r($pages);

            return $this->build_menu($array,$parent_id = 0,$level=0);
    //return $array;
}




                   function build_menu($array, $parent = 0, $level = 0)
                    {
                            $ret = '<ul>';
                            foreach($array as $m)
                            {
                                if($m['parent_menu'] == $parent)
                                {
                                        $ret .= '<li>'.$m['menu_link'];
                                        $ret .= $this->build_menu($array, $m['parent_menu'], $level + 1);
                                        $ret .= '</li>';

                                }
                            }
                            return $ret.'</ul>';
                            print $ret;
                    }
```

I don't under stand why this is happening . my recursive function return errors.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is that in your recursive call to the function build_menu you pass the parent of the current page instead of the current page.

```
function build_menu($array, $parent = 0, $level = 0)
{
    $ret = '';
    foreach($array as $m)
    {
        if($m['parent_menu'] == $parent)
        {
            $ret .= '<ul>';
            $ret .= '<li>' . $m['menu_link'] . '</li>';
            $ret .= $this -> build_menu($array, $m['menu_link'], $level + 1);
            $ret .= '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

I don't know why you pass also $level, but maybe need to you for something.

Comment: hello, this function return infinite loop.

Comment: its return  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in E:\xampp\htdocs\Achievers\application\libraries\dayanamicMenu.php on line 85

Comment: As you can see in the link above the function work fine. Try to post full code.